# angularjs google map zoom map after max zoom exceeded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to zoom the google map after it exceeds it maximum zoom level. I google it and didn't find any solution. I am building a rooftop app any one can please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) show that the `google.maps.MapOptions` object has a property called `maxZoom` that you can set *when creating the map* to set the maximum amount the map can be zoomed.

You can also set `minZoom` in the same way. So as long as your users don't need to be able to zoom very far out in order to move around effectively (e.g. if your app moves the map programmatically somehow) then you may even want to set the `minZoom` to a realistic value to ensure that people don't accidentally zoom too far out when trying to scroll down the page (I personally do that all the time with embedded google maps and it drives me crazy). But be careful with this: you don't want to ruin the user experience by removing your users' ability to navigate the map efficiently.

One thing you'll notice when reading the description of the `maxZoom` and `minZoom` parameters is that the docs don't specify the range of acceptable numbers. So how are you to figure out what numbers to pass in? And how do you change the max zoom after creating the map?

If the `Map` object is bound to a variable called `map`, then you can get the current zoom with `map.getZoom()` and you can set the current zoom with `map.setZoom(zoom)` where `zoom` is floating-point Number such that `zoom >= 0`. (Note: These methods get and set the "zoom" property of the `Map` object, but making changes directly to `map.zoom` will *not* cause the map to change, so be sure to use the getter and setter methods).

The most-zoomed-out level for the `zoom` property is `0`, but the most-zoomed-in level will actually vary depending on *where* in the world the map is focused.  (This makes sense, since street-level in some places could be a mile underground in others depending on elevation.) And at some zoom level, Google will no longer have (usable) satellite images.

Enter the [MaxZoomService Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MaxZoomService). This object's constructor can be found at `google.maps.MaxZoomService`. The instances of this class have only one useful method: `getMaxZoomAtLatLng` which takes a `LatLng` instance or a `LatLngLiteral` as its first parameter and a callback function to handle the result as its second.

A `LatLng` instance can be created with the `google.maps.LatLng` constructor, and a `LatLngLiteral` is just a normal object literal that has a `lat` property and a `lng` property. But since you'll probably be passing in a `LatLng` object from another method like `map.getCenter()`, you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Here's an example showing how to find out the maximum zoom available on the Satellite View at the center of the map's current view.

```
var mzs = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();       // Create a MaxZoomService instance
var mapCenterLatLng = map.getCenter();            // Get a LatLng instance
var handleMaxZoom = function(res) {               // Callback Function accepting MaxZoomResult instance
     if (res.status === "OK") {
         // handle success
         console.log("Max Zoom: " + res.zoom);    // Print max possible zoom
         map.setZoom(res.zoom);                   // Set the zoom to the max possible
     } else {
         // handle failure
         console.log("Oops");
     }
};
mzs.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(mapCenterLatLng, handleMaxZoom);
// => Max Zoom: [Number]
```

**Edit:**

If you really want to exceed the maximum zoom level (not just the *default* maximum zoom level as described above) your only real option is going to be using css transforms. Depending on how complicated the page layout is, this could end up being pretty difficult to get perfect.

I should note that this is typically ***not*** a good idea even if you *can* manage to get the layout to look good and the images to not be blurry. It carries all the same problems as using CSS to transform `canvas` elements (and some additional problems on top because it's not as simple as dealing with just a single DOM element). One notable problem is that applying CSS transforms will not affect the internal coordinates of the map (like those contained in click events) so you'll have to transform those every time you want to use them. Additionally, since the primary map div (the one returned by `map.getDiv()`) has to sit inside a container, this method will often cause it to overflow its container and you'll have to deal with that added complexity.

If you still want to do it, then here are some pieces of the puzzle that may help:

```
var mapCanvas = map.getDiv();            // The "main" div element that contains the map
var container = mapCanvas.parentElement; // You'll need some sort of container here
var scalingFactor = 1.5;                 // => Set a scaling factor (ex: 1.5 means scale it to 150% normal size)
/* Use CSS zoom property and/or vendor transforms to scale the map (though you could do this in straight CSS instead) */
mapCanvas.style.zoom = scalingFactor;
mapCanvas.style.MozTransform = 'scale(' + scalingFactor + ')';
mapCanvas.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(' + scalingfactor + ')';
/* Then try to fit the scaled map back into its container, which will depend on how you're displaying it */
mapCanvas.style.width = "calc(100% / " + scalingFactor + ")"; // The CSS 'calc()' method might be useful here
```

Comment: is there any other alternative ? actually its a  roofing app and i need more exactly more zoom at any cost(with blurry images too)

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I'm pretty sure the image that Google delivers when you're at the map's `maxZoom` is the highest-quality satellite image available. Beyond that, you'll have to work outside of the Google Maps API and scale the DOM element directly, like I described at the bottom. CSS `scale` and `zoom` transforms are probably your best options at that point, though you can of course access them with JS (like I showed) or with pure CSS. If you're going to zoom in really far, you should probably make sure the overflow is hidden somehow because the controls will be scaled too.

Comment: @SelFish I noticed that you've only asked two questions on SO before. If you feel that my answer sufficiently answers your question (if you think it's the "right answer" or at least "good enough") you are able to "accept" the answer if you want. Note: You're under no obligation to do so; I just figured I'd point it out to you in case you were not aware. (Also: Marking an answer as "accepted" does not "close" the question. Others will still be able to post answers if they come across this, though it's possible that they may be less likely to do so if there is already an accepted answer.)